# Jest + Nuxt + Nuxt-Fire is failing in test suite

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, jestjs, nuxt.js

I'm using Nuxt with Nuxt-Fire (https://github.com/lupas/nuxt-fire)

When I launch my test I get this error `[Vue warn]: Error in config.errorHandler: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'ref' of undefined"`

This is happening because of this section in my App

```
mounted() {
    this.initiate(window.instaroomId)

    let connected = this.$fireDb.ref(".info/connected")
    this.getConnection(connected)
},
```

It looks like the this.$fireDb is not called. The module is normally loaded in nuxt.config.js. How can I make this work?

Comment: Could you also provide content of your test case?

Comment: I am following because I have the same issue with another library (@nuxt/axios) not being loaded in the test suite

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test, that `this.$fireDb.ref(".info/connected")` was called you can mock it like this:

```js
import { shallowMount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import SomeComponent from '@/components/SomeComponent/SomeComponent.vue'

let wrapper

describe('SomeComponent.vue Test', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = shallowMount(SomeComponent, {
      mocks: {
        $fireDb: {
          ref: jest.fn()
        }
      }
    })
  })
  it('$fireDb.ref was called', () => {
    expect(wrapper.vm.$fireDb.ref).toBeCalled()
    expect(wrapper.vm.$fireDb.ref).toBeCalledWith('.info/connected')
  })
})
```

Or if you want the test just to pass `created()` hook and test another functionality you can just mock `$fireDb.ref` without testing that it was called.